# React Redux + redux persist : only part of the data persists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

it's a react-native app (redux-pattern) using redux-persist, to persist the data for time when user doesn't have internet connection.

Problem is only part of the data is being persisted. See the screenshot bellow. `auth` is persisted and loaded from `AsyncStorage` without any problems. but others `courses` , `evaluations`, ... are persisted partly.
for example courses/courses includes the userId of 1, but it's an empty object.

[image]

****UPDATE new screenshot, auto-rehydrate with logs on:
[image]
Store.js :

```js
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from "redux-persist";
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from "redux";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import createLogger from "redux-logger";
import rootReducer from "./rootReducer";

const logger = createLogger();

const store = createStore(rootReducer, compose(
 applyMiddleware(thunk, logger),
 autoRehydrate()
));

persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage});

export default store;
```

auth.reducer.js

```js
import * as types from "./auth.actions";
export const INITIAL_STATE = {
 token: null,
 users: {}
};

export default function auth(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
 const {users, token} = state;
 switch (action.type) {
  case types.AUTH_LOGIN:
  users[action.payload.userId] = {
   token: action.payload.token,
   ///.... continues
  };
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
   loading: false,
   token: action.payload.token,
   user: action.payload.userId,
   users: users
  });
  case types.AUTH_LOGIN_FAILED:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
   users,
   token
  });
  case types.AUTH_LOGOUT:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
   token: "",
   user: "",
   users: {}
  });
  default:
   return state;
 }
}
```

There are few more components, for example see the codes for Courses :

courses.reducer.js

```js
import * as types from "./courses.actions";

export const INITIAL_STATE = {
  courses: {}
};

export default function courses(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
  const {courses, lectures, schedule, events, discussion} = state;
  switch(action.type){
    case types.GET_COURSES:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      courses: action.payload.courses,
      lectures: action.payload.lectures,
      schedule: action.payload.schedule,
      events: action.payload.events,
      discussion: action.payload.discussion
  });
    case types.GET_COURSES_FAILED:
    return state;
    case types.BOOK_COURSE:
    return state;
    case types.UNBOOK_COURSE:
    return state;
    case types.BOOK_COURSE_FAILED:
    return state;
    case types.UNBOOK_COURSE_FAILED:
    return state;
    default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

Any solutions please?

*** UPDATE (requested by petsome)
courses.actions.js

```js
export const GET_COURSES = 'GET_COURSES';
export const GET_COURSES_FAILED = 'GET_COURSES_FAILED';
export const BOOK_COURSE = 'BOOK_COURSE';
export const UNBOOK_COURSE = 'UNBOOK_COURSE';
export const BOOK_COURSE_FAILED = 'BOOK_COURSE_FAILED';
export const UNBOOK_COURSE_FAILED = 'UNBOOK_COURSE_FAILED';

import Functions from '../common/Functions';

export const getCourses = (users) => {
  return dispatch => {
    Functions.getCoursesAPI(users)
    .then((data)=>{
      const {courseList, lectureList, schedule, eventList, discussion, coursesArray} = data;
      return dispatch(coursesSuccess(courseList, lectureList, schedule, eventList, discussion, coursesArray));
      //return dispatch(coursesFailed('e'));
    })
    .catch((e)=>{
      return dispatch(coursesFailed(e));
    });
  };
};

export const bookCourse = (user, courseId, callback) => {
  return dispatch => {
    Functions.bookCourse(user, courseId, callback)
    .then((data)=>{
        return dispatch(bookCourseSuccess(data));
    })
    .catch((e)=>{
      return dispatch(bookCourseSuccessFailed(e));
    });
  };
};

export const unbookCourse = (user, courseId, callback) => {
  return dispatch => {
    Functions.unbookCourse(user, courseId, callback)
    .then((data)=>{
        return dispatch(unbookCourseSuccess(data));
    })
    .catch((e)=>{
      return dispatch(unbookCourseSuccessFailed(e));
    });
  };
};

const coursesSuccess = (courses, lectures, schedule, eventList, discussion, coursesArray) => {
  return {
    type: GET_COURSES,
    payload: {
      courses: courses,
      lectures: lectures,
      schedule: schedule,
      events: eventList,
      discussion: discussion,
      coursesArray: coursesArray
    }
  }
};

const coursesFailed = (e) => {
  return {
    type: GET_COURSES_FAILED,
    payload: {
      error: e
    }
  }
};

const unbookCourseSuccess = (data) => {
  return {
    type: UNBOOK_COURSE,
    payload: {
      data: data
    }
  };
};

const unbookCourseSuccessFailed = (e) => {
  return {
    type: UNBOOK_COURSE_FAILED,
    payload: {
      error: e
    }
  };
};

const bookCourseSuccess = (data) => {
  return {
    type: BOOK_COURSE,
    payload: {
      data: data
    }
  };
};

const bookCourseSuccessFailed = (e) => {
  return {
    type: BOOK_COURSE_FAILED,
    payload: {
      error: e
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: You need to include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. In summary: "Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem; Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem; Verifiable – Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem".

Comment: @AndrewWillems most of the code have been removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure if:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
            loading: false,
            token: action.payload.token,
            user: action.payload.userId,
            users: users
        });
```

Be the best option.

In my experience to keep your reducer up to date, you must use `...state`

```
case YOUR_NAME_CASE:
            return {
                ...state,
                //Your keys for update
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. let me try it. I'll update here.

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience, I would advice that you add a timestamp in your redux store to indicate when the data was persisted. So that when the client tries to fetch new data from the server, it can request for the timestamp from the server to compare with clients' before updating the redux store. There can be inconsistency with syncing the persisted data on the client and the one coming from the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't get the point. how is your answer related to the question? State is not being persisted after it's changed.

Comment: After every actions, the nextState is persisted. that's the purpose of the redux-persist. So if you want to persist some parts, then you either use whitelist or blacklist options provided by the library.

Comment: that's my problem actually. nextState is not being persisted!

Comment: can you attach your action creators that handles the dispatching of the action used in the reducer? According to your redux store screenshot, you are not merging the data to the store correctly.

Comment: when is your redux-persist action dispatched? it should be completed before any other action is dispatched. That can cause inconsistencies with the data in the redux store if done after. if you have that, then check the data return from the getCourses async action. Your reducer function looks okay, although you can refactor it a bit.

Comment: I've re-written the whole action creators and now it works fine :) Thanks.